# How to go back to a previous line in python?

Tags: python, loops

How can i make it so that if the last line is true it goes back to beginning of the loop?

```
p = int(input("input value of p: ")  
q = int(input("input value of q: ")  
import random  
list(range(-q, q)):
while p != p + 1:
    x1 = random.choice(l)
    x0 = random.choice(l)
    if((q == x0 * x1) and (-p == x0 + x1)):
        print(x0, x1)
    else:
        if((q != x0 * x1) or (-p != x0 + x1)):
            #What do i put here to return to the beginning of the loop?
```

Comment: you're looking for [continue](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue)

Comment: What do you want it to do if the last statement is ```False```?  Because it is the last statement in the suite, the loop *automatically returns* to the top and checks the ```while``` condition - you shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: `list(range(-q, q)):` ...did you mean: `l = range(-q, q)` ?  you have a syntax error currently

Answer (score 0):

if the condition `((q == x0 * x1) and (-p == x0 + x1))` is not met the loop will automatically go back to the start

there's no need to formulate the inverse logic `if((q != x0 * x1) or (-p != x0 + x1))` inside the `else` block since that is the meaning of `else`.

your while loop is `while p != p + 1` but currently you don't change the value of `p` anywhere, so you're not really checking anything useful. if you just want to keep looping you can do `while True` (but you will have to have a `break` in your loop somewhere!)

you haven't said what is the intention of the code but I'm guessing you wanted it to stop after printing the matching values, in which case you could just do:

```
import random

p = int(input("input value of p: ")  
q = int(input("input value of q: ")  
l = range(-q, q)

while True:
    x1 = random.choice(l)
    x0 = random.choice(l)
    if ((q == x0 * x1) and (-p == x0 + x1)):
        print(x0, x1)
        break
```

Answer (score -2):

This might work for you.

I have also added a way so the user can not enter any string or numbers that are negative.)

```
l=[]
while q<=0:
    try:
        q=int(input("Enter a number"))
    except:
        print("That is not a number!")
        continue
while p<=0:
    try:
        p=int(input("Enter a number"))
    except:
        print("That is not a number!")
        continue
    import random  
    list(range(-q, q))
    print(l)
    while p != p + 1:
        x1 = random.choice(l)
        x0 = random.choice(l)
        if((q == x0 * x1) and (-p == x0 + x1)):
            print(x0, x1)
        else:
            if((q != x0 * x1) or (-p != x0 + x1)):
                continue
```

This should go back to the top of the loop.
The `continue` command will only work in loops, no where else...

Comment: What happens if ```(q != x0 * x1) or (-p != x0 + x1)``` is ```False```?

Comment: even if it's False, It'll go back to the start of loop and check the condition `p != p + 1` and the rest is based on the result of that condition

Comment: When you find yourself typing almost identical code twice, you should find yourself thinking *"this could be a function"*...